# Time change when using jdbc input plugin in logstash

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I have a column `create_time` which value is '2018-01-12 16:27:59';
When I use `jdbc input plugin` in `logstash` to synchronous data to `Elastic Search`. The time has changed to '2018-01-12T08:27:59.000Z' in es. I know the timezone of es is UTC, which is different from my timezone. How can I fix the data?
Here is my config file:

```
 input {
    jdbc {
      jdbc_connection_string => 'jdbc:mysql://*:3306/*?'
      jdbc_user => '*'
      jdbc_password => '*'
      jdbc_driver_library => 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar'
      jdbc_driver_class => 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
      statement => 'select * from test where create_time > :sql_last_value'
      use_column_value => true
      tracking_column => "create_time"
      tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
      jdbc_default_timezone => "Asia/Shanghai"
      jdbc_fetch_size => "1000"
      schedule => '* * * * *'
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => json_lines
    }

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => 'localhost:9200'
        index => 'test-1 '
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date format you require in the mappings:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Refer [Elastic Date Formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

*You can also change the select statement and format the date as your require before sending it to logstash.*